# Derivative of Projection | Derivative of Matrix w.r.t matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus, projection-matrices

I am trying to take derivative of following function  w.r.t matrix $X$ where $X$ is not a square matrix hence singular.

$$
f(X) = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T
$$
I used product rule for the function with $U = X, V = (X^TX)^{-1} and W = X^T$.
I am stuck at how to take derivative of matrix w.r.t to a matrix. I used the vec concept given in

http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~pift6266/A06/refs/minka-matrix.pdf

it solved $U$ but not sure about $V and W$. Is there a better way to solve the function ?

Comment: This mapping takes a matrix to another matrix, so what you're looking for is a Jacobian. Before going further, can you give a bit more detail as to why you want this? The form you give looks more like a solution to a least squares problem, so I'm wondering if there's a better shortcut.

Comment: My actual problem is following $||Pi - Pj||^2_F$ (square of Frobenius norm).
Where $Pi =$ the equation in the question with $X=Ui$ .
I want to solve the actual problem w.r.t Ui.
For that I opened the norm and I got multiple terms, e.g. one of the term is $tr[PiPi^T]$.
To take derivative of this w.r.t to Ui  i used chain rule. I solved 
$tr[PiPi^T] w.r.t to Pi$ and now I have to take derivative of $Pi $ w.r.t Ui and that's where I am stuck.

Comment: So to clarify, your original problem is to minimize $\|X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T-P_j\|$ with respect to $X$? There is a way of computing this jacobian explicitly but it's a huge pain... I guess first product rule, then chain rule for that inverse, which you can try to do by googling Hessian of log determinant (since the gradient of log determinant is inverse). There should be something on directional derivatives for matrix inverse, which in this case is "in the direction of X".

Comment: @whyyes yes, that's it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I have a similar gradient and sharing would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

$$\eqalign{
P &= \{{\rm known}\} \\
X &= \{{\rm unknown}\} \\
\\
Y &= X^T  \\
F &= X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \;\doteq\; XX^+ = Y^+Y \\
F^2 &= Y^+YF = Y^+Y = F = F^T \\
FY^+ &= Y^+YY^+ = Y^+ \\
M &= (F-P) \quad\implies\quad dM = dF \\
S &= P+P^T \quad\implies\quad M+M^T = 2F-S \\
\\
\phi &= \tfrac 12\big\|M\big\|^2_F \\
 &= \tfrac 12M:M \qquad\qquad\big\{{\rm Frobenius\:Product}\big\}\\
\\
d\phi &= M:dM \\
 &= M:dF \\
 &= M:\Big(dX\,X^+ + Y^+dY
  - Y^+\Big(Y\,dX+dY\,X\Big)X^+\Big) \\
 &= \big(MY^+ - Y^+YMY^+\big):dX + \big(X^+M - X^+MXX^+\big):dY \\
 &= \big(MY^+ -Y^+YMY^+\big):dX +\big(M^TY^+ -Y^+YM^TY^+\big):dX \\
 &= \big(Y^+YSY^+ -SY^+\big):dX \\
 &= \big(X^+SXX^+ -X^+S\big):dY \\
\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial Y}
 &= (X^+SXX^+ -X^+S) \;\doteq\; 0 \\
\\
X^+S &= X^+SXX^+ \quad\implies\quad S = XX^T \\
\\
}$$
Thus any decomposition (Cholesky, LU, etc) of the symmetric
matrix $S = (P+P^T)$ of the form $XX^T$ produces a serviceable solution of the zero gradient condition and minimizes the objective function $\phi$.